# É possível impedir que um dos atributos de um objeto seja serializado em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Há alguma maneira de impedir que um dos atributos de um objeto seja serializado?

Tome como exemplo o objeto abaixo. Se eu não quiser que `propriedade2` seja serializado, como eu poderia implementar isso?

```js
var obj = {
  propriedade1 : 'teste 1',
  propriedade2 : {
    subpropriedade1 : 'teste 2 - 1',
    subpropriedade2 : 'teste 2 - 2'
  },
  propriedade3 : 'teste 3',
  propriedade4 : {
    propriedade1 : 'teste 4 - 1'
  }
}

var obj2 = new Object();
obj2.propriedade1 = 'teste 1';
var prop2 = new Object();
prop2.subpropriedade1 = 'teste 2 - 1';
prop2.subpropriedade2 = 'teste 2 - 2';
obj2.propriedade2 = prop2;
obj2.propriedade3 = 'teste 3';
var prop4 = new Object();
prop4.propriedade1 = 'teste 4 - 1';
obj2.propriedade4 = prop4;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2));
```

Comment: Queres evitar que algumas propriedades sejam passadas para o JSON? e sabes de antemão quais elas são?

Comment: @Sergio, no caso, eu sei quais eu não quero, portanto, exceto essas que não quero, todas devem ser serializadas

Comment: Pergunta interessante e 3 respostas interessantes! Todos ganham :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uma outra maneira é criar uma propriedade não enumerável. Propriedades não enumeráveis não são acessadas em laços `for..in`, nem são incluídas na geração de JSON.

Exemplo:

```js
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'teste', { enumerable: false, writable: true });
o.teste = 10;
console.log(o.teste);          // 10
console.log(JSON.stringify(o)) // "{}"
```

Comment: Esta solução pode ter algum efeito colateral caso o valor da propriedade seja enumerável por natureza? Por exemplo, se o valor da propriedade for uma lista, você estaria definindo a lista como não enumerável? Isso pode afetar outras estruturas no código, tal como um laço que itera sobre esse valor?

Comment: Creio que não, cada propriedade tem seus próprios *property descriptors*, e eles determinam os atributos da propriedade em relação ao objeto a que ela pertence. Nesse meu exemplo, se `teste` fosse um objeto, você poderia enumerar as chaves dele com `for..in`. Mas nunca encontraria esse objeto ao enumerar as propriedades do objeto `o`. Não sei se estou sendo claro...

Comment: Sim, foi claro, mas mesmo assim é um cuidado a ser tomado, pois altera o comportamento do objeto. De qualquer forma, conhecimento a mais agregado.

Comment: Genial! Não fazia ideia que isso existia

Answer (score 11):

Para simplificar o entendimento, criarei um exemplo mais próximo da realidade:

```
const obj = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 34,
    "parents": [
        {
            "name": "Derp",
            "age": 63,
            "gender": "male"
        }, {
            "name": "Derpina",
            "age": 62,
            "gender": "female"
        }
    ]
};
```

Supondo que a intenção é serializar o objeto `obj` ignorando o atributo `age`. Um detalhe é que não somente o próprio objeto possui o atributo `age`, como também objetos filhos possuem (nesse caso, os dois objetos em `parents`). Se a intenção, nesse caso, é de remover todos os atributos `age`, não importando onde esteja, há duas soluções (outras foram abordadas nas outras respostas):

**Primeira solução:** passar como segundo parâmetro de `JSON.stringify` uma lista dos atributos que deseja manter ao serializar o objeto. Porém, essa lista de atributos não deve abordar apenas os atributos do objeto original, mas todos os atributos de todos os objetos relacionados que é desejado manter. Por exemplo, os objetos internos a `parents` possuem o atributo `gender` que o objeto principal não possui e mesmo assim tal atributo deve ser listado:

```js
const obj = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 34,
    "parents": [
        {
            "name": "Derp",
            "age": 63,
            "gender": "male"
        }, {
            "name": "Derpina",
            "age": 62,
            "gender": "female"
        }
    ]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, ["name", "parents", "gender"]));
```

Se `gender` não for listado, o atributo será removido dos objetos internos ao efetuar a serialização.

**Segunda solução:** também utilizando o segundo parâmetro de `JSON.stringify`, mas agora definindo uma função que executará a lógica de manter ou não um valor no objeto. A função recebe dois parâmetros: a chave, nome do atributo, e seu respectivo valor. A lógica aqui seria bem simples: se a chave condizer com o atributo que desejamos remover, retornamos o valor `undefined`, caso contrário, retorna o próprio valor.

```js
const obj = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 34,
    "parents": [
        {
            "name": "Derp",
            "age": 63,
            "gender": "male"
        }, {
            "name": "Derpina",
            "age": 62,
            "gender": "female"
        }
    ]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, value) {
    if (key == "age") {
        return undefined;
    }
    
    return value;
}));
```

Esta forma é relativamente mais versátil que a primeira, pois ao invés de especificar quais atributos você deseja manter, você especifica quais atributos deseja remover, não importando a estrutura do restante do objeto.

### Não modificando objetos internos

Ambas as soluções removem o atributo dos objetos mais internos, então, se a intenção é de mantê-los, removendo o atributo do objeto principal, outras soluções são necessárias.

**Função toJSON:** como apresentado na [resposta do L.Albano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241976/5878), é possível definir uma função `toJSON` no objeto que será chamada ao serializar o mesmo. O resultado da serialização será, na verdade, a serialização do retorno desta função. L. Albano mostrou como fazer o clone do objeto manualmente, mas é possível fazer de forma dinâmica e, depois, remover o atributo desejado.

```js
const obj = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 34,
    "parents": [
        {
            "name": "Derp",
            "age": 63,
            "gender": "male"
        }, {
            "name": "Derpina",
            "age": 62,
            "gender": "female"
        }
    ],
    toJSON: function () {
        
        // Clona o objeto:
        const clone = Object.assign({}, this);
        
        // Remove o atributo desejado:
        delete clone["age"];
        
        // Retorna o clone modificado:
        return clone;
    }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Desta forma, apenas o atributo `age` do objeto principal é removido, enquanto dos objetos internos são mantidos.

> Clonar o objeto utilizando `Object.assign` só é possível a partir do ECMAScript 5 (ES6), porém, se desejável, existem [*polyfills*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294740/1452488). Outra técnica de clonar objetos é combinar `JSON.parse` com `JSON.stringify`, porém esta técnica não é aplicável neste exemplo pois geraria uma recursão infinita.

Comment: Apenas uma dúvida, essa sintaxe de função como a que você passou no segundo exemplo está disponível em todos os navegadores?

Comment: Essa solução afeta diretamente objetos internos e pode não funcionar em todos os casos (pois os atributos destes objetos também são filtrados). Estou verificando este problema.

Comment: @ArturoTemplário [quase todos](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions), editarei a resposta assim que possível.

Comment: Injusta a pontuação desta resposta em relação às outras!

Answer (score 10):

Ainda não consigo comentar, então apenas acrescentando a resposta do @AndersonCarlosWoss. Uma terceira opção, é o próprio objeto decidir quais propriedades ele deseja serializar:

```js
var obj = {
  prop1: "String",
  prop2: 1,
  prop3: true,
  toJSON: function(){
    return {
      prop1: this.prop1,
      prop2: this.prop2
    };
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Gostei, não sabia que isso funcionava. Li que não é padrão (realmente `toJSON` não está em `Object.prototype`), mas a especificação mais recente fala de ver se existe um método com esse nome ao tentar serializar qualquer coisa.

Comment: @bfavaretto, exatamente, `toJSON` não faz parte de `Object.prototype`, ele é uma propriedade procurada no momento da serialização, onde alem do nome tbm é verificado o se o tipo é uma `function` e assim esta é chamada para a serialização customizada. [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Esperando você terminar para eu dar meu julgamento final

Comment: Muito bom, +1 também